# How to show show the Second page title in the page

Tags: posts, title

I am using a page hierarchy and I want to show the title of the 2nd parents 
The structure is something like

Main Page

Main Page > Second page

Main Page > Second page > Third page

Main Page > Second page > Third page > Fourth page

I want to show the Second page title in the Fouth page.

How can i do this? Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

get_post_ancestors() returns all of the ancestors hierarchically. As you only want to display the 2nd level post title on 4th post page, you can do something like -

```
global $post;

$parents = get_post_ancestors( get_the_ID() );

if( count($parents) == 4 ){

    // ancestor1 = 1st parent, ancestor2 = second.
    echo get_the_title($parents['1']); // index starts from 0, 1 = 2nd item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [`get_post_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)

According to the documentation it returns an array of the ancestor page IDs